# Achievement system in and IDLE python game using pycharm

Tags: python

I am trying to use an achievement system in my game. The game is like cookie clicker except you type and enter the letter "L" over and over and can upgrade the effect done by each type. I am trying to make it so when you get a certain amount of coins, like 1000, it will display that you have achieved the 1000 coins achievement, however it doesn't seem to work. Here is the code:

```
if coins == 1000:
    print("")
    print("You have a new achievement!")
    print("[✔] - Earn 1,000 points")
    print("You have 1/6 coin achievements")
    print("")
if coins == 10000:
    print("")
    print("You have a new achievement!")
    print("[✔] - Earn 10,000 points")
    print("You have 2/6 coin achievements")
    print("")
```

Comment: Do you have the correct tabbing for the code?

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't work. Is you indentation like here?

Comment: I had an indentation like yours but it copy pasted over incorrectly. I don't get an error, it just doesn't work in the game. The way I have it set up, it only prints: "[✔] - Earn 10,000 points" when you get exactly 1000 points which doesn't always work, because say I had 980 points, I might skip right to 1001 and it would skip right over the message. So I tried a greater than or equal to 1000 but It printed: "[✔] - Earn 10,000 points" every time I earned more points. Is there a way it will display: "[✔] - Earn 10,000 points" once I get 1000 or more points and only display it once?

Comment: This should be part of your question

Comment: BTW: You could use `elif` for the second comparison anyway, because the cases are exclusive: if first is true the second cannot be true at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Your specific problem is that you're using the wrong comparator.  If you use `==`. you're checking if the value exactly equals.  You're interested in when a player "achieves" the value, so switch your comparators out for `>=`.  That way, when a player goes from 980 to 1001 points, `1001 >= 1000` evaluates to `True`.

Note this will print the text every time you check, even if they've already got the achievement, so perhaps something like the following would be useful:

```
has_1000_achievement = False
has_10000_achievement = False

if coins >= 1000 and not has_1000_achievement:
    has_1000_achievement = True
    print("")
    ...
```

The solution provided by P i would undoubtedly work, but I believe it's not something you're ready to fluently understand at your current level.

Comment: However, if it is > 10000 it still does ... so you also need to compare < 10000

Comment: Good point, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yours is making assumptions about the achievement structure, and if you're incorrect, or if you're correct but the requirements change, yours is much less flexible.  Looking at it again, I notice there are to be 6 levels of achievements, but yours goes to infinity.  In any case, for someone like OP who is still at the stage of learning which comparators to use, your solution introduces WAY too much.

Comment: Think about it this way:  When you play any game, you can get achievements in any order.  The way games will take care of this is multiple variables, (or a hashmap, or a bloom filter, or a mask, whatever).  Instead of counting how many achievements the player has, and algorithmically determining what achievement that means they're meant to get next, each achievement's check code is it's own logical block.

Comment: Read the OP again; he's trying to make an achievement system.  Within that, he's having an issue with _this_ type of achievement.  Who are you to say these are the only achievements?  Why did you introduce the complexity you did, instead of just answering the question?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** After the OP added a comment the question got a little more clear to me. Maybe you could try the following (which is of course just an example as the OP did not provide a minimal running peace of code):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

numCoinAchievements = 0
nextCoinLevel = 1000

for coins in range(0, 100000, 33):
    if coins >= nextCoinLevel:
        numCoinAchievements += 1

        if numCoinAchievements == 1:
            nextCoinLevel = 10000
        elif numCoinAchievements == 2:
            nextCoinLevel = 15000
        else:
            break
    print("")
    print("You have a new achievement!")
    print("[✔] - Earn %d points" % nextCoinLevel)
    print("You have %d/6 coin achievements" % numCoinAchievements)
    print("")
```

Of course you have to adept the code to your needs, but it should make the problem clear!